# Dealing with Closures and Futures in Scala

Tags: scala, closures, future

I have the following method that does some handling with `Future`s:

```
def registerNewUser(user: User): Future[Either[ServiceError, User]] = async {
  val encryptedUser =
    user.copy(encrypt(user))

  def checkResultAndFetchUser(result: WriteResult, encryptedEmail: String): Future[Either[ServiceError, User]] = {
    if (result.hasErrors)
      Future.successful(Left(ServiceError(result.writeErrors.map(_.errmsg).toString)))
    else
      userByEmail(encryptedEmail)
  }

  def handleInsertError(result: WriteResult): Either[ServiceError, User] = {
    if (result.code contains 11000)
      Left(ServiceError("Email already exists"))
    else
      Left(ServiceError(result.writeErrors.map(_.errmsg).toString))
  }

  val result = userCollection.insert(encryptedUser).map( writeRes =>
    checkResultAndFetchUser(writeRes, encryptedUser.email)
  ).recover {
    case res: WriteResult => Future.successful(handleInsertError(res))
  }

  await(result.flatMap(fut => fut))
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. The `encryptedUser` local variable is being used in the `checkResultAndFetchUser` method, the `userCollection.insert(encryptedUser)` returns a `Future`, so is there any chance that another `encryptedUser` might be captured in the `checkResultAndFetchUser` method? That would mean, I'm doomed!
2. Is this a good way of dealing with `Future`s and its handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean with your first question, but there is only one `encryptedUser` value, so even though both functions return a `Future` they both use the same `encryptedUser`.

For handling you `Future`s :

- You aren't really using async / await, since you are only using `await` on the "result" `Future`.
- You are using `map` on `userCollection.insert()` and then using `result.flatMap(fut => fut)`, which can be simplified to using `flatMap` directly.

  ```
  userCollection.insert(encryptedUser).flatMap( writeRes =>
    checkResultAndFetchUser(writeRes, encryptedUser.email)
  )
  ```
- Which could also be written as a for comprehension.

The end result could look like :

```
def registerNewUser(user: User): Future[Either[ServiceError, User]] = { 
  def checkResultAndFetchUser(result: WriteResult, encryptedEmail: String) = ???

  def handleInsertError(result: WriteResult) = ???

  def insertUser(user: User): WriteResult =
    userCollection.insert(user).recover {
      case res: WriteResult => handleInsertError(res)
    }

  val encryptedUser = user.copy(encrypt(user))

  for {
    writeRes <- insertUser(encryptedUser)
    user     <- checkResultAndFetchUser(writeRes, encryptedUser.email)
  } yield user
}
```

Comment: What I means is that what would be the effect of having multiple threads calling the registerNewUser method? Would the encryptedUser from thread1 be used in the thread of encryptedUser2? Would I have this situation with the code structure that I have above?

Comment: Evertime you call `registerNewUser` this function has its own `encryptedUser`, but I would think `encrypt(user)` returns the same result for the same input `user` ?

Comment: Yes, encrypt returns the same result for the same input user! That is not my concern. When I'm closing in on a local variable, I should be careful when the closed variable is going to be executed in another thread. I hope my implementation is safe against this!

Comment: If `User` is an immutable case class (which it probably should), it doesn't matter because you cannot change `encryptedUser` in any of the threads.

Comment: My question was if the execution of the Future userCollection.insert(user) happens in a different thread than to the  checkResultAndFetchUser method? In that case the  checkResultAndFetchUser would see another encryptedUser or?

Comment: Like I wrote at the start of my answer, both functions use the same `encryptedUser`.